# How to set up nginx setting to distribute different servers from request pointing different domain?

Tags: nginx

I would like to set up nginx to distribute different servers from request pointing dirrerent domain.
The nginx server environment is below.

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
nginx 1.11.8
 * in configure with --with-stream parameter. build & install from source.

My image is.

```
  server1.testdomain.com ssh request ->(global IP) *nginx server -> (local IP)192.168.1.101 server
  server2.testdomain.com ssh request ->(global IP) *nginx server -> (local IP)192.168.1.102 server
```

- nginx server is same glocal IP and same server.

nginx.conf is ...

```
stream {
        error_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/stream.log info;

        upstream server1 {
                server 192.168.1.101:22;
        }

        upstream server2 {
                server 192.168.1.102:22;
        }

        server {
                listen 22 server1.testdomain.com;
                proxy_pass server1;
        }

        server {
                listen 22 server2.testdomain.com;
                proxy_pass server2;
        }
}
```

But...
nginx: [emerg] the invalid "server1.testdomain.com" parameter in・・
error occurred. It seems like impossilbe to execute such as listen "22 server1.testdomain.com".

And,
I tried to write "server_name" in "server".
nginx: [emerg] "server_name" directive is not allowed here in・・・
don't permit to use "server_name" in "server".

How do I write config file to distribute difference server for difference domain request?
If you have a idea or information, could you teach me?

Comment: If `server1` and `server2` both point to the same global IP address, then the server blocks are not different `address:port` pairs as [required by the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html#listen).

Comment: Like "listen server1.testdomain.com:22"?

Comment: I can't do it. nginx: [emerg] duplicate "server1.testdomain.com:22" address and port pair in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible with nginx because `stream` module is L3 balancer. SSH protocol works at L5/7.

Its not possible at all because ssh negotiation does not include destination host name.

You can do what you want only using two different IP or using two different ports. In both cases nginx can forward connection, but much better to use `iptables` in this case.

Comment: I understood. Can I achieve by another OSS application like Squid? If you know it, let me know it.

Comment: You can do what you want only using two different IP or using two different ports.

Comment: Yes.. I also understand it. But I have one fixed IP. And if difference port, it seems like difficult to connect by ssh.

Comment: Not really. `ssh user@server2.test.com:2222`. Each ssh client have port field too. For example, for my servers I am always changing default 22 port for stop bruteforcing bots.

Comment: I see. For security issue, I should use different port number  changing default ssh port number. Thank you.